# Issue with asynchronous (non blocking) methods with Sanic

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, sanic

So I'm trying to use Sanic to to some asynchronous web requests as I have some special ones that take a few seconds to get back, but want to do other requests in the mean time from the client. Here is an example method that seems to still be blocking other calls from the client while its waiting for the lib.getAlarmState() to come back. (lib.getAlartmState() is a call to a C library using pythons ctypes that takes about 3 seconds to return and returns an Int type.)

According to what I'm seeing in documentation for sanic, simply defining the method as async should do what I'm looking to do? I've tried adding an await in front of lib.getAlarmState() but I'm not sure I'm using that quite right.

```py
@app.route('/processjson')
async def processjson(request):

    vals = lib.getAlarmState()

    return response.json({"alarm:" : vals})
```

I expect that while the shown method is off doing its thing, I should be able to call other methods from the client and get responses.

Comment: So further investigation has lead me to believe my issue is that the lib.getAlarmState() must also be run asynchronously regardless of the fact that its in an asynchronous method. Therefore I must make use of asyncio seperately to run the lib.getAlarmState(). So my next question is, whats the simple solution to do that? I'm reading and reading examples but I can't seem to find the exact steps required to simply run a method asynchronously and get its return.

Answer (score 1):

That is correct. Sanic will not be able to convert blocking calls to asynchronous. Perhaps, what you can try instead is to run that in a seperate task.

```py
async def get_alarm_state_wrapper():
    return lib.getAlarmState()

@app.route('/processjson')
async def processjson(request):

    vals = await asyncio.gather(get_alarm_state_wrapper())

    return response.json({"alarm:" : vals})
```

Comment: Well I've implemented that which seems to be running okay at least, however it still seems to be blocking other requests coming in from the client while its waiting for lib.getAlarmtState() to come back.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately... not too much you can do to force a blocking function into a non-blocking. At least in the asyncio world. Some other concurrency techniques might help. The problem is the underlying function needs to be capable of operating asynchronously. See also answer provided here: https://github.com/huge-success/sanic/issues/1602

Comment: Alright well I guess the hang up is that my ctypes function call itself can't be called asynchronously.